# What is the correct way to extend Material UI ListItem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using TypeScript 3.4.5 and Material UI 4.2 and with the following piece of code:

```
interface MyItemProps {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

function Item({ name, value, ...props }: ListItemProps<'li', MyItemProps>): ReactElement {
    return (
        <ListItem {...props} className="item">
            <ListItemText primary={name} secondary={value || '-'} />
        </ListItem>
    );
}
```

**I'm getting `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'` error.** Why?

I've been looking into the type definitions for `ListItem`, but I can't figure out what's going on:

```
export interface ListItemTypeMap<P, D extends React.ElementType> {
  props: P & {
    alignItems?: 'flex-start' | 'center';
    autoFocus?: boolean;
    button?: boolean;
    ContainerComponent?: React.ElementType<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>;
    ContainerProps?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>;
    dense?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    disableGutters?: boolean;
    divider?: boolean;
    focusVisibleClassName?: string;
    selected?: boolean;
  };
  defaultComponent: D;
  classKey: ListItemClassKey;
}

declare const ListItem: OverridableComponent<ListItemTypeMap<{ button?: false }, 'li'>> &
  ExtendButtonBase<ListItemTypeMap<{ button: true }, 'div'>>;

export type ListItemClassKey =
  | 'root'
  | 'container'
  | 'focusVisible'
  | 'default'
  | 'dense'
  | 'disabled'
  | 'divider'
  | 'gutters'
  | 'button'
  | 'secondaryAction'
  | 'selected';

export type ListItemProps<D extends React.ElementType = 'li', P = {}> = OverrideProps<
  ListItemTypeMap<P, D>,
  D
>;

export default ListItem;
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is "type widening", but I don't really know what's happening and why.

**Could somebody please explain what's going on? Most importantly, what is the correct way of extending a Material UI component?**

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [well established issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14971) over on the material-ui github. Apparently it stems from using booleans to do union discrimination - I'm still new to TS so only have a general understanding of what that means!

The cleanest way to get past this which I found from those threads (without overwriting `button` with explicit `any` in the component props, ew) is by casting `button` as true directly on to the `ListItem`:

```
interface MyItemProps {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

type MyListItem = ListItemProps<"li", MyItemProps>;

function Item({ name, value, button, ...props }: MyListItem): ReactElement {
    return (
        <ListItem {...props} className="item" button={button as true}>
            <ListItemText primary={name} secondary={value || '-'} />
        </ListItem>
    );
}
```

Comment: I now understand TS than I did at the time I asked the question. And you're *almost* right - it's connected to intersection types. Basically, if the element type is "li", then the button prop must be set to false or undefined. If the element type is "div", then the button prop must be set to true. With all of that in mind, I believe it's not correct to cast the button prop to true just FYI :) It simply shouldn't be set at all.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes a lot more sense. The way I stumbled on this issue, I was trying to create a wrapping component which was ambivalent about the type of element that `ListItem` would create, meaning I would want to pass it either a `component` or `button` prop depending on the context. My original answer still seems like the best way to achieve that, although I'm aware that casting `button` is not ideal! Possibly this is also essentially just MUI telling me not to try and do that if I want to stay type-safe, which is also a fair conclusion and something I'll have to think about.

Answer (score 2):

It all boils down to how [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) work.

Basically, you can have one, or the other:

- If the element type is "li", then the button prop must be set to false or undefined
- If the element type is "div", then the button prop must be set to true.

So, in my case, because I was using "li" as a type parameter with the `ListItemProps` generic type, I can't just pass the `button` prop through. It must be omitted instead (or alternatively, set to false):

```
interface MyItemProps {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

function Item({ name, value, button /* omit the prop, don't pass it down to ListItem */, ...props }: ListItemProps<'li', MyItemProps>): ReactElement {
    return (
        <ListItem {...props} className="item">
            <ListItemText primary={name} secondary={value || '-'} />
        </ListItem>
    );
}
```